# Is it okay to fly from a Swiss airport to Vietnam with German residence permit?

Tags: zurich, vietnamese-citizens

I am Vietnamese living in Germany now. I have German residence permit.
I'm planning to fly to Vietnam from Zurich (or Basel) airport. Is it possible? Or do I have to fly from a German airport?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your residency permit is valid for the entire Schengen area, not just for Germany itself. Therefore you may fly from Switzerland or just about any other Schengen airport.

Enjoy your trip.

Comment: To be clear, the residency permit is valid for _travel_ in the entire Schengen area, not for _residence_ in Schengen.

Comment: Also, to be clear, you will, of course, need your passport for Vietnam.